# Java vertx 3.2 file upload using bodyhandler

Tags: java

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read exception in vertx3.0.  I tried in many ways. The simple formupload is working fine. But when i use body handler, it is throwing below exception. Can anybody help ?

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders;

import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;

/*
 * @author Gogs
 */

public class TestServer extends AbstractVerticle {

  // Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner.runExample(TestServer.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    // Enable multipart form data parsing
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
      routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end(
          "<form action=\"/form\" ENCTYPE=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"POST\" name=\"wibble\">\n" +
           "choose a file to upload:<input type=\"file\" name=\"myfile\"/><br>"+
          " <input type=\"submit\"/>"+
          "</form>"
      );
    });

    // handle the form
    router.post("/form").handler(ctx -> {

      ctx.request().setExpectMultipart(true);
      ctx.request().uploadHandler(upload -> {
          upload.exceptionHandler(cause -> {
            ctx.response().setChunked(true).end("Upload failed");
          });

          upload.endHandler(v -> {
            ctx.response().setChunked(true).end("Successfully uploaded to " + upload.filename());
          });
          // FIXME - Potential security exploit! In a real system you must check this filename
          // to make sure you're not saving to a place where you don't want!
          // Or better still, just use Vert.x-Web which controls the upload area.
          upload.streamToFileSystem(upload.filename());
        });


    });

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8090);
  }
}

Am seeing the below exception.


Feb 02, 2016 6:48:54 PM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase

SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read

    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.checkEnded(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:426)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.setExpectMultipart(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:322)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.setExpectMultipart(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:166)
    at com.vertx.http.upload.TestServer.lambda$1(TestServer.java:43)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:221)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:93)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.doEnd(BodyHandlerImpl.java:155)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.uploadEnded(BodyHandlerImpl.java:135)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.lambda$null$35(BodyHandlerImpl.java:109)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerFileUploadImpl.notifyEndHandler(HttpServerFileUploadImpl.java:213)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerFileUploadImpl.lambda$handleComplete$165(HttpServerFileUploadImpl.java:206)
    at io.vertx.core.file.impl.AsyncFileImpl.lambda$doClose$226(AsyncFileImpl.java:470)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16(ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It really pains me to see the API of vertx.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the request body twice. The first read is via `BodyHandler` (see `BodyHanderImpl`) and the second is by your own handler (see `HttpServerRequestImpl` and `HttpServerFileUploadImpl`).

`BodyHandler` reads the body from the request fully and makes it available in `context.body`. The way your router is configured:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
```

the body will be read completely on every single request handled by your router.

Your handler is also reading the request body fully and writing its contents to the file system. Your router is configured to only execute your handler when a POST is made to `/form`.

To recap the flow, when you submit the upload to `/form` `BodyHandler` is reading the request fully, storing the contents in context.body, and marking the request body as read. Your router matches the uri path to your upload handler and attempts to read the body again but since it has already been read the exception is raised.

Some thoughts...

If your intent is to write the uploaded file to the file system you really don't need BodyHandler configured in your router. You would want to use BodyHandler when you needed the body in memory in order to process it in some way. Unless you intend to execute a handler on very single request received by your router, you should not configure a handler without matching criteria (i.e. `router.route().handler(...)`). A good use case for this type of handler is CookieHandler.

Comment: Great thanks. I removed router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create()); and it works fine. However, my requirement is load the verticle (verticle.java) and load router (route.java) from verticle.java. Basically dependencies. when i use this upload code in route.java, it is not routing to the path. It is showing the same error, "Body already been read". Do you have any example that loads the verticle and load the route dependencies ?

Comment: From your comment I am not sure what you mean. Could you update your question with with the verticle.java and router.java source that your having problems with?

Comment: Sorry for the late reponse. Actually we moved out of this and run the seperate vertx server since we need to deliver our project. Now again we got the requirement to have in our main webserver verticle. So we have a main verticle running in some port ( Eg: 8280 ). when the route come (Eg: /form ) then it has to do the fileupload as mentioned above. But we are getting the above exception. Can you please help ?.

Answer (score 0):

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.vertx/vertx-web/3.0.0/io/vertx/ext/web/impl/RouterImpl.java#RouterImpl

Gogs, I was looking at this code, and quite possible we could implement our own Router or something similar that could then be managed in the accept method...

Comment: ignore this... creating our own body handler would be best

Answer (score 0):

We can probably create our own bodyhandler...
provide a list of ignored routes in our config file:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.vertx/vertx-web/3.0.0/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/BodyHandlerImpl.java#BodyHandlerImpl

Comment: Sure hector. I was looking the same. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/BodyHandlerImpl.java